# XSLT Sorting Issue w/ String Containing Text and Numbers That Are Single and Double Digit

Tags: xml, xslt

I am looking for assistance with addressing an issue I'm encountering with a XSLT stylesheet I'm applying to a basic XML file, which will output basic HTML for a portal we're building. Specifically, I am trying to apply a <xslt:sort select="" /> to the content I'm outputting based on a title element, which includes text and single and double digit numbers and the sort element puts double digit numbers before single digits (see example below):

Example XML source file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <TitleList>
    <book>
        <title>Book 1: Part 3. Buying and Selling Stuff</title>
        <author>Jon Doe</author>
        <PubDate>2010</PubDate>
     </book>
     <book>
      <title>Book 1: Part 7. Making Stuff</title>
      <author>Jane Doe</author>
      <PubDate>2012</PubDate>
      </book>
      <book>
        <title>Book 1: Part 8. The Art of Creating Things </title>
        <author>Jon Doe</author>
        <PubDate>2013</PubDate>
      </book>
     <book>
      <title>Book 1: Part 10. Stuff Happens</title>
      <author>Jane Doe</author>
      <PubDate>2014</PubDate>
     </book>
     </TitleList>
```

Example XSLT:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
       version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" />
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
           <div id="titleList">
               <table>
                   <tr>
                       <th>Title List</th>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                       <xsl:call-template name="retrieveTitles"></xsl:call-template>
                   </tr>
               </table>
           </div> 
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="retrieveTitles">
    <xsl:for-each select="TitleList/book">
     <xsl:sort select="title" /> 
     <tr>   
      <td>  
        <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
      </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="author" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="PubDate"/>
        </td>
     </tr>   
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Resulting HTML with titles out of order:

```
    <html>
     <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
     </head>
     <body>
     <div id="titleList">
     <table>
        <tr>
           <th>Title List</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <tr>
              <td>Book 1: Part 10. Stuff Happens</td>
              <td>Jane Doe</td>
              <td>2014</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
              <td>Book 1: Part 3. Buying and Selling Stuff</td>
              <td>Jon Doe</td>
              <td>2010</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
              <td>Book 1: Part 7. Making Stuff</td>
              <td>Jane Doe</td>
              <td>2012</td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
              <td>Book 1: Part 8. The Art of Creating Things </td>
              <td>Jon Doe</td>
              <td>2013</td>
           </tr>
        </tr>
     </table>
  </div>
    </body>
   </html>
```

How do I get configure the ordering element for the XSLT script in order to ensure that the titles are ordered consecutively when the jump is made from single digit numbers to double digit numbers? Thanks for your time!

Regards,

wyattburp86

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To minimize the example to the problem at hand, consider the following:

```
<xsl:template match="/TitleList">
    <table>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="book">
            <xsl:sort select="substring-before(substring-after(title, 'Book ' ), ':')" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
            <xsl:sort select="substring-before(substring-after(title, 'Part ' ), '.')" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="book">
    <tr>
        <td>  
            <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
        </td>
    </tr>       
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: That worked! I incorporated the sort select functions you provided into my environment and it sorted correctly. I am encouraged that your suggestion included "substring-before" since I was looking at that initially, but you helped to fill in the pieces I was missing! Many thanks - cheers!